# Navigating screen through bottom bar flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

What I am trying to do is change screen from the bottom navigation bar. This bottom bar is created in a form of slider.How can I return  a new screen when the user slides  from one item to another ?

Right now it only returns a screen text based on the List of String tabnames.

Should I return a new screen on the switch method or how I could achieve it ?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

const List<String> tabNames =  <String>[
  'Reports', 'Reminders', 'Savings', 'Subscription', 'BudgetPlanner', 
];




class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _screen = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabNames.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Navigation example'),
        ),
        // ignore: unnecessary_new
        body: new TabBarView(
          children: List<Widget>.generate(tabNames.length, (int index) {
            switch (_screen) {
              case 0: return Center(
                child: Text('First screen, ${tabNames[index]}'),
                
              );
            
            } throw ErrorHint("Hello");
          }),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            AnimatedCrossFade(
              firstChild: Material(
                color: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .primaryColor,
                child: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabs: List.generate(tabNames.length, (index) {
                    return Tab(text: tabNames[index].toUpperCase());
                  }),
                ),
              ),
              secondChild: Container(),
              crossFadeState: _screen == 0
                              ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                              : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a List of Text Widgets you should pass Screen Widget List.

```
const List<String> sections=  <String>[
  Page1(), Page2(), Page3(), Page4(), Page4(), 
];

  body: new TabBarView(
      children: sections
    ),
```

I suggest using [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) really useful for changing screen with bottom bar navigations here is a

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  PersistentTabController controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: controller,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      backgroundColor:
          Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), // Default is Colors.white.
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
          true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
      stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows:
          true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
      decoration: NavBarDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
        colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
      ),
      popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
      popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
      itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
        // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
      screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
        // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
        animateTabTransition: true,
        curve: Curves.ease,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      ),
      
      navBarStyle:
          NavBarStyle.style12, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
    );
  }
}

List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
  return [FeedPage(), ProfilePage()];
}

List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
  return [
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.map),
      title: ("Map"),
      activeColorPrimary: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
      inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.profile_circled),
      title: ("Profile"),
      activeColorPrimary: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
      inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
    ),
  ];
}
```